# Generalization of the isoperimetric inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

#### Preliminaries

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a simple (sufficiently smooth) closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with length $L$ and enclosing an area $A$. Suppose furthermore that $\gamma:[0,L]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a parametrization-by-arclength for $\Gamma$ so that $|\gamma '(s)|=1$ for every s, i.e.

$$L = \int_0^{L} |\gamma'(s)| $$

The [total (absolute) curvature](http://www2.mat.dtu.dk/people/S.Markvorsen/DISPLAY/TEMP/PROOPG/KnottedCurves/Milnor.pdf) can be defined by

$$C = \int_0^{L} |\gamma''(s)| = \int_0^{L} \kappa(s)$$

It can be shown that $C\ge 2\pi$. Equality holds iff $\Gamma$ is convex.

The [isoperimetry inequality](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/two-cute-proofs-of-the-isoperimetric-inequality/)

$$4\pi A\le L^2$$

(equality holds iff $\Gamma$ is a circle) can be stated using another derivative of $\gamma$

$$\Omega = \int_0^{L} ||\gamma''(s)|'| = \int_0^{L} |\kappa'(s)|$$

A closed curve $\Gamma$ is a circle $\mathsf{O}$ iff $\Omega = 0$. (**Edit**: Pietro correctly pointed out that the initial formula $\int_0^{L} |\gamma'''(s)|$ would not make sense.) This implies

$$\left(( L_{\Gamma} = L_{\mathsf{O}})  \wedge (C_{\Gamma} = C_{\mathsf{O}}) \wedge (\Omega_{\Gamma} \ge \Omega_{\mathsf{O}})\right) \rightarrow (A_{\Gamma} \le A_{\mathsf{O}})$$

for all closed curves $\Gamma$ and circles $\mathsf{O}$.

#### Question

I wonder if and how it could be shown that a generalization of the last proposition holds:

> $$ \left((L_{\Gamma} = L_{\Gamma'})  \wedge (C_{\Gamma} = C_{\Gamma'})
>  \wedge (\Omega_{\Gamma} \ge \Omega_{\Gamma'})\right) \rightarrow (A_{\Gamma} \le
>  A_{\Gamma'}) $$

for all closed curves $\Gamma, \Gamma'$, i.e. of two curves of the same length and the same absolute curvature the one with greater change rate of curvature has the smaller area.

How would this – probably [using Fourier analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27164/why-is-fourier-analysis-so-handy-for-proving-the-isoperimetric-inequality) – be shown for ellipses with the same perimeter?

Comment: Is the formula for Ω what you really mean? Here Ω=0 implies γ′′′=0 , that is $\gamma(s)=as^2+bs+c$, right?  

Comment: $\Omega = 0$ is supposed to mean "constant curvature".

Comment: Did I understand your question correctly (I edited it according to my
understanding:-) ?

Comment: @Alexandre: Absolutely, thanks for the improvement!

Comment: Your formula for $\Omega$ is still not good. You are integrating a full derivative (and singularities are only at points where the curvature is zero), so the result is always 0.


Comment: @Sergei: You are right, I corrected it again.

Comment: This is certainly false for arbitrary pairs $\Gamma,\Gamma'$, just by counting the degrees of freedom. Concerning the ellipses, are you interested in the case when both curves are ellipses, or one of them?

Comment: @Sergei: When you ask me: in both cases.

Comment: Hi Hans -- why did you delete your question about the distance between two curves? I had written up a somewhat detailed answer, but couldn't submit because the questions was deleted. (Your question was good by the way). If you are still interested you can email me at vixie@speakeasy.net and I will send you what I wrote, or undelete the question and I will post the answer. (I know this is an unusual use of the comments, but since you have no contact info on your user page this was the only option ;~)