# Is there good reference for proof complexity?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory, proof-complexity

I am asking if there are some good or standard references for proof complexity theory? I didn't find references when I search in internet. Thanks!

Comment: Previously posted on math.SE (with no answers): [Reference for proof complexity theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2410811).

Comment: Perhap you could expand on what you mean by "proof complexity theory"? In the meantime, maybe this earlier MO question is relevant: [Deep theorems and long proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149115/6094). In particular, see Joel Hamkins' references there.

Answer (score 14):

These are three books that I know:

1. [Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/logical-foundations-proof-complexity#85v2LkjvjCOYq21Z.97)
2. [Bounded Arithmetic, Propositional Logic and Complexity Theory](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=0521452058)
3. [Logical Foundations of Mathematics and Computational Complexity](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319001180), Proof complexity chapter

Also, I suggest you read the following papers:

1. [The lengths of proofs](http://www.math.cas.cz/%7Epudlak/length.pdf)
2. [Bounded Arithmetic and Propositional Proof Complexity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiA7fH8_5rWAhWLPFAKHYuGALQQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucsd.edu%2F%7Esbuss%2FResearchWeb%2Fmarktoberdorf95%2Fpaper.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHH5a_cOZekZvuoSGsx7eFTtnyGqQ)

==============================================

**Update.**
Jan Krajíček wrote a [new book](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108242066) on this topic recently. You can find the final manuscript of it [here](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/prf2.pdf).