# Diagonalizability of Gaussian random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ matrix whose elements are i.i.d. sampled from a normal distribution of zero mean and unit variance. Is $X$ diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ with probability 1? Is there a good reference for diagonalizability of random matrices?

Comment: Are you assuming that X is symmetric? Are you using real or complex scalars?

Comment: If you work in $M_n({\bf C})$ then the subset of matrices that are not diagonalizable over ${\bf C}$ has Lebesgue measure zero, and hence for any probability density on $M_n({\bf C})$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, a random element of $M_n({\bf C})$ will be almost surely diagonalizable over ${\bf C}$

Comment: @YemonChoi X is not symmetric; every element is sampled independently from a normal distribution. Thanks for the result over C. I'd be more curious to know the density when X is real-valued.

Comment: But why would you expect a "typical" real matrix to be diagonalizable over R? (The particular Gaussian i.i.d. model you are asking about is the Ginibre ensemble, so we know that the spectrum is almost surely a disc (in the asymptotic sense as n tends to infinity. However, my point is that even ignoring probability theory, it is very easy for real matrices to have complex eigenvalues)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I am very new to random matrix theory. I think I am curious to know the density of real-valued diagonalizable matrices whose eigenvalues can be complex numbers.

Comment: @YemonChoi Do you have a reference for this? I'd like to know more details about what you just said.

Comment: see also https://mathoverflow.net/q/12657/11260

Comment: please clarify: the matrix $X$ is real, but do you wish to diagonalize over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$? the probability for a random real matrix to have all real eigenvalues is vanishingly small, typically only $\sqrt n$ of the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The matrix $X$ is real, but I wish to know the density of $X$ diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure of real matrices that are not diagonalizable
over $\mathbb{C}$ equals to 0, see for example [On the computation of Jordan canonical form](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3142770), so the probability for a random matrix with a continuous probability distribution to be non-diagonalizable vanishes. To put it differently, the set of real matrices without multiple eigenvalues is dense, and a matrix without multiple eigenvalues is definitely diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Is it known whether the set of unitarily diagonalizable matrices, i.e., normal matrices, is dense in $R^{n\times n}$?

Comment: a small perturbation of a normal matrix spoils that property, so it cannot be a dense set, can it?